# Modify request field value before saving in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building app using laravel 5.
I have such code:

```
public function store(ArticlesRequest $request, Pages $page)
{

    $parentSlug = Pages::getParentSlug($request->parent_id);
    $slug = ($request->slug)? $request->slug:$request->generic_title; 
    $validSlug = $request->makeSlug($slug);
    $request->slug = $validSlug;

    $page->create($request->all());
}
```

I want to update some data before saving, like slug, in this case , but it's not saving a slug field, if I directly don't input from form field. How can I update $request containing element values? For example $request->slug = $validSlug; and it save my edited slug in DB.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to move that logic to an [attribute mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in your model

Comment: @lukasgeiter it's clear how to set and get attributes  when it's about one field, but can you tell me how can I merge two input fields using attribute mutator ? For example I have publish_date and publish_time, which I insert in DB together. Thank you! :)

Comment: There isn't really a nice solution for this. You could pass an array with both values though... If you need more help please ask a new question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can manage request values like this:

```
$request->offsetSet('slug', $validSlug);
```

However I agree with the comment above, it would be far better to manage a default value inside your Pages model.

**UPDATE:** I previously had two methods, one of this no longer works as of Laravel 5.1 (thanks @omarjebary). Updated answer.

Comment: Or just use `$request->offsetSet('slug', $validSlug)`

Comment: getInputSource() is a protected method in Laravel 5.1+ so can only be called by instances of the Request class itself or classes that inherit from it.
The offset() method no longer exists, replaced with offsetSet(), though this is public.

Comment: @omarjebari Thanks for the notice, that must have changed since 5.0. Does the second method still work?