# How to validate date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In validate method I have following :

```
$this->validate($request, ['test_date' => 'required|unique:test_db']);
```

The `test_date` in `test_db` is stored as unix time.
On submission of form, I get `$request->get('test_date')` in `mm/dd/Y`

The unique validation does not work because I get date in `mm/dd/Y` which is different from db (unix time).

How to make it unique in this validation?

Comment: So do you want to change `mm/dd/Y` to unix time ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844102/date-format-not-validating-in-laravel

Comment: unique:test_db.test_date

Comment: You can first convert your date with unix time and then validate it with db date

Comment: Share one date sample ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
//get date from request
$date = $request->get('test_date');

//add the converted date to request
$request->request->add(['new_date_field'=> DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date)->getTimestamp()]);

//validate the updated date field
$this->validate($request, ['new_date_field' => 'required|unique:test_db']);
```

Adding fields to the request : [Laravel is there a way to add values to a request array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107903/laravel-is-there-a-way-to-add-values-to-a-request-array)

**UPDATE :**
You can update existing field using offsetSet method:

```
    //get date from request
    $date = $request->get('test_date');

    //update date in request
    $request->offsetSet('test_date', DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date)->getTimestamp());

    //validate the updated date field
    $this->validate($request, ['test_date' => 'required|unique:test_db']);
```

Updating request fields : 
[Modify request field value before saving in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995111/modify-request-field-value-before-saving-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the date format then everything will be fine, so try this:

```
$date = $request->get('test_date');

$newDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date ));
```

use this `$newDate` in the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Provide feature called Accessors and mutators.

Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

For more information visit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Hope this will help you.